# how to detect asp.net webforms page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

if a page contains a Viewstate in the source. Does this mean the webpage is using ASP.NET WebForms or could this also be an MVC project ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think MVC uses viewstate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [ASP.NET MVC and Web Forms Integration](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_MVCandWebForms.html)

> IIS needs to be able to figure out whether a given request is an
>   ASP.NET MVC or a Web Forms request. Once it can figure that out, IIS
>   can send the request to the appropriate handler and the application
>   behaves as you’d expect.

check these lines from that nice article.

> Caution
>
> Watch out for ViewState! Though many parts of the ASP.NET Framework
>   are accessible by both Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC, the most significant
>   piece of the Web Forms Framework that is not supported in ASP.NET MVC
>   at all is ViewState. Most often, ViewState is used for a Web Forms
>   Page to communicate with itself, so the chances of running into
>   ViewState issues when cross-posting between Web Forms pages and
>   ASP.NET MVC controllers are slim.
>
> However, when transitioning your Web Forms application to ASP.NET MVC,
>   be on the lookout for any code in your Web Forms application that
>   expects ViewState — the ViewState data will not exist during the
>   course of an ASP.NET MVC request so code that depends on it will
>   likely break!

Answer (score 0):

There is no ViewState in MVC. So if you find a `ViewState` element, you can be pretty sure that it's an ASP.NET WebForms page.

Although, since ViewState is just a regular hidden input element with name/id "__VIEWSTATE", there is a slight chance, that someone added such an element (in a non-ASP.NET page) with exactly that name and id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"
  value="contents go here" />
```

Comment: Ok so if I find such element I can say that for 99% it is a WebForms application right? I am just testing and I still can't figure out if MVC or WebForsms is the best for me. At the moment I think WebForms is easy to work with the EntityFramework and Database Mapping but I am not sure... That's why I am looking around at some big sites to figure out what they are using

Comment: I don't think working with EntityFramework is easier with either MVC or WebForms. But the programming model used by MVC and WebForms is totally different.

Comment: BTW: it is also possible to use WebForms with no (or minimal) ViewState